# searching for a pattern and placing it within another in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have about 256 lines in a text file that look like `/*0*/L"",` I want to remove the last `,` and then put the remaining as a function argument `code.append(/*0*/L"");` I tried doing it with `vim` but I don't have much experience in it. how can we place something within something else in `vi` or `vim`?

Comment: use substitute command: `:%s@foo@bar@`

Comment: @kev this only changes lines with `/*0*/L""`. I have other similar lines that start with a `/*[upto 3 digits]*/L"[empty or some values]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:%s#\v(/\*0\*/L""),#code.append(\1);#`

- `:%s` : substitute all lines
- `#` : alternative separator
- `\v` : use very magic mode (see `:h magic`)
- `(/\*0\*/L""),` : capture the regex, excluding the trailing comma
- `\1` : insert first captured group

Answer (score 2):

this line would do the substitution on all lines in your buffer, only if the line ending with comma. No matter you had `/*0*/L"",` or `/*123*/L"",`

```
%s/\v(.*),$/code.append(\1)/
```

if you want to shrink the sub on certain pattern, change the `.*` part in the above cmd to fit your needs.